# How to mock Injector instance in Angular / Jasmine tests?

Tags: angular, mocking, jasmine, karma-jasmine, testbed

I need to test my service which is using `Injector` to inject services instead of `constructor()`.

The main reason for which I use this way is the large number of services which extends my common `SimpleDataService`. Here are `CompanyService`, `ProductService`, `TagService` etc., and everyone extends SimpleDataService. So I don't want to define more than neccessary parameters to `super()` calls.

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { Injector, NgModule } from '@angular/core';

export let InjectorInstance: Injector;

@NgModule({
  // ...
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    InjectorInstance = this.injector;
  }
}
```

**simple-data.service.ts**

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { InjectorInstance } from 'src/app/app.module';
import { PaginateInterface } from 'src/app/models/paginate/paginate.interface';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

export class SimpleDataService<T> {
  public url = environment.apiUrl;
  private http: HttpClient;
  public options: any;
  public type: new () => T;

  constructor(
    private model: T,
  ) {
    this.http = InjectorInstance.get<HttpClient>(HttpClient);
  }

  getAll(): Observable<PaginateInterface> {
    return this.http.get(this.url + this.model.api_endpoint, this.options)
      .pipe(map((result: any) => result));
  }
}
```

**simple-data.service.spec.ts**

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';
import { Tag } from 'src/app/models/tag/tag.model';
import { SimpleDataService } from './simple-data.service';

describe('SimpleDataService', () => {
  TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting());

  const model = new Tag();
  const simpleDataService = new SimpleDataService(model);
});
```

Now I get `TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined` error message. And this occurs because of this line:

```js
this.http = InjectorInstance.get<HttpClient>(HttpClient);
```

The `InjectorInstance` is the `undefined` here.

How can I mock an `Injector` instance into my `InjectorInstance` property avoiding this way?:

```js
  constructor(
    private model: T,
    private injectorInstance: Injector,
  ) { }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part of the issue is that you are using the `export let` to declare the `InjectorInstance`. This type of declaration makes it illegal to modify the field from any other file (as in: test file). One way to change that would be to make the `InjectorInstance` a static field of the `AppModule` class, as in:

```
export class AppModule {
  static InjectorInstance: Injector;

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    AppModule.InjectorInstace = injector;
  }
}
```

Then you could use the `TestBed` in that field, as the interface of `Injector` is actually very simple and only contains the `get` method. As in :

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({(...)});
}));

beforeEach(() => {
  AppModule.InjectorInstance = TestBed;
});
```

In the current implementation you should also be able to simply do:

```
new AppModule(TestBed)
```

I think it's less descriptive what this line does, but it leaves your `InjectorInstance` safer in production code.

Keep in mind that all this can make your tests affect each other, because once you change that field it will be changed from the perspective of every other test, even in other files.

Wether exchanging the dependency injection pattern for service locator pattern is a good idea is a completely different discussion.

Comment: just for clarify, when you say "change that field" you say "change the InjectorInstance field", right? If this right, then it isn't has any sideeffect, because the original `Injector` instance never changing. I only use it's `get()` method.

Comment: Yes, in the real app the injector instance will not change. Just keep in mind it may change between tests as there will be a new `TestBed` created between them.

Comment: yes, thanks! This is great advice and answer too! I need to implement it, then it's working I will mark as "solve my problem". Thanks again!

Comment: So here is a fast result: I put the `static InjectorInstance: Injector;` code into my `AppModule` class, then in my service changed to this: `this.http = AppModule.InjectorInstance.get<HttpClient>(HttpClient);` and the build is OK, but in browser I get `Cannot read property 'get' of undefined` error message. Of course the `this.InjectorInstance = this.injector;` not working, because of `this.InjectorInstance` field is static... and undefined. The `static InjectorInstance: Injector = new Injector();` not working, because it's an abstract class... How can I define it?

Comment: I edited the answer to show how to set the static field.